# List HTML tags from a String

Tags: java, html, parsing, tags

I have a String and from which I want to list all the HTML tags present within it. Is there any library available to do this job?

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Take a look here, I think you will find everything you want -> http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Comment: You might be able to use Jtidy, check out http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/howto.html

Comment: http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to extract only the HTML tags from your String.

```
    package com.overflow.stack;

    /**
     *
     * @author sarath_sivan
     */

    public class ExtractHtmlTags {

        public static void getHtmlTags(String html) {
            int beginIndex = 0;
            while(beginIndex!=-1) {
                beginIndex = html.indexOf("<", 0);
                int endIndex = html.indexOf(">", beginIndex+1);
                String htmlTag = "";
                try {
                    if(beginIndex!=-1) {
                        htmlTag = html.substring(beginIndex, endIndex+1);
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(htmlTag);
                html = html.substring(endIndex+1, html.length());
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String html = "<html><body><h2>List HTML tags from a String</h2>hello<br /></body></html>";
            ExtractHtmlTags.getHtmlTags(html);
        }

    }
```

But, I don't understand what you are trying to do with the extracted HTML tags. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://jsoup.org/ 
Not sure it allows to get list of tags but you can get the list iterating DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The parser from HTMLUnit can take a String and return an a structured result:

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HTMLParser.html

Answer (score 0):

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://yoursite.com'))
page.css("*").map{|x| x.name}.flatten.uniq
```